# FORM based login not redirecting to stored request

Tags: java, apache, hibernate, jsp, jboss

Migrating from JBoss EAP 5.2.0 to JBoss EAP 6.1.0. The user is correctly directed to the login.jsp page, but after successful authentication via j_security_check, the redirect to the originally requested Main.jsp page does not happen, the user is stuck on login.jsp.

The logs look like Main.jsp is initially saved as the request but since its redirected to login.jsp, login.jsp is saved over Main.jsp as the new request.

Comparing with a working deployment from JBoss EAP 5.2.0, I noticed the working log contains:

[org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter] (http-0.0.0.0-8443-1:)  Requested cookie session id is ...
[org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase] (http-0.0.0.0-8443-1:) Security checking request GET /myApp/

Here is the JBoss EAP 6.1.0 server output:

```
Security checking request GET /myApp/
[org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[sc]' against GET /Main.jsp --> false
[org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[all]' against GET /Main.jsp --> true
[org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[sc]' against GET /Main.jsp --> false
[org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[all]' against GET /Main.jsp --> true
[org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)  Calling hasUserDataPermission()
[org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)   User data constraint already satisfied
[org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)  Calling authenticate()
[org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1) Save request in session 'Db-s0UWZpAj9Z0g1QBRcDkhe'
[org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/myApp].[jsp]] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)  Disabling the response for futher output
[org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/myApp].[jsp]] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)  The Response is vehiculed using a wrapper: org.apache.catalina.connector.Response
[org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)  Failed authenticate() test
[org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1) Security checking request GET /myApp/login.jsp
[org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[sc]' against GET /login.jsp --> false
[org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[all]' against GET /login.jsp --> true
[org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[sc]' against GET /login.jsp --> false
[org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[all]' against GET /login.jsp --> true
[org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)  Calling hasUserDataPermission()
[org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)   User data constraint already satisfied
[org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)  Calling authenticate()
[org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1) Save request in session 'Db-s0UWZpAj9Z0g1QBRcDkhe'
[org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/myApp].[jsp]] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)  Disabling the response for futher output
[org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/myApp].[jsp]] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)  The Response is vehiculed using a wrapper: org.apache.catalina.connector.Response
[org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)  Failed authenticate() test
[org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1) Security checking request GET /myApp/images/com_logo.jpg
[org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[sc]' against GET /images/com_logo.jpg --> true
[org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[all]' against GET /images/com_logo.jpg --> true
[org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)  Calling hasUserDataPermission()
[org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)   User data constraint has no restrictions
[org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)  Calling accessControl()
[org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)   Checking roles null
[org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1) Passing all access
[org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)  Successfully passed all security constraints
[org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1) Security checking request POST /myApp/j_security_check
[org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1) Authenticating username 'admin'
[org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1) Authentication of 'admin' was successful
[org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1) Redirecting to original '/myApp/login.jsp?accept=true'
[org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)  Failed authenticate() test ??/myApp/j_security_check
[org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1) Security checking request GET /myApp/login.jsp
[org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[sc]' against GET /login.jsp --> false
[org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[all]' against GET /login.jsp --> true
[org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[sc]' against GET /login.jsp --> false
[org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[all]' against GET /login.jsp --> true
[org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)  Calling hasUserDataPermission()
[org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)   User data constraint already satisfied
[org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)  Calling authenticate()
[org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1) Restore request from session 'Db-s0UWZpAj9Z0g1QBRcDkhe'
[org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1) Authenticated 'admin' with type 'FORM'
[org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1) Proceed to restored request
[org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)  Calling accessControl()
[org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)   Checking roles GenericPrincipal[admin(HttpInvoker,AppRole,)]
[org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1) JBWEB000017: User [admin] has role [AppRole]
[org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1) Role found:  AppRole
[org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)  Successfully passed all security constraints
[org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1) Security checking request GET /myApp/images/com_logo.jpg
[org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[sc]' against GET /images/com_logo.jpg --> true
[org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[all]' against GET /images/com_logo.jpg --> true
[org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)  Calling hasUserDataPermission()
[org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)   User data constraint has no restrictions
[org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)  Calling accessControl()
[org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)   Checking roles GenericPrincipal[admin(HttpInvoker,AppRole,)]
[org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1) Passing all access
[org.apache.catalina.authenticator] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1)  Successfully passed all security constraints
```

web.xml:

```
  <security-constraint>
    <display-name>un-protected</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>sc</web-resource-name>
      <description>My Resources</description>
      <url-pattern>/login-redirect.html</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>/images/app_logo.jpg</url-pattern>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
      <http-method>POST</http-method>
      <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
      <http-method>PUT</http-method>
      <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
      <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
      <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
  </security-constraint>
  <security-constraint>
    <display-name>protected</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>all</web-resource-name>
      <description>all</description>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
      <http-method>POST</http-method>
      <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
      <http-method>PUT</http-method>
      <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
      <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
      <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <description>Users authorized to use MyApp.</description>
      <role-name>MyRole</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>My Realm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
      <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
      <form-error-page>/login.jsp?loginFailed=true</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
  </login-config>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>MyRole</role-name>
  </security-role>
```

I also noticed the following on the server log:

```
DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8443-1) PBOX000287: Failed to open properties file from URL: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: /opt/web/jboss/jboss-eap-6.2/standalone/configuration/my-app-users.properties
```

I was able to get it to redirect, but not quite sure why it works differently between JBoss 5 and 6 EAP. My login initially prompts the user with a notification form, that the user must accept to go to the login form (both contained in login.jsp). The notification form contains:

```
<form action="login.jsp">
    <input type="hidden" name="accept" value="true"/>
    <div align="center"><input type="submit" value="Accept"></div>
</form>
```

Changing the action to "/[my_apps_base_url>]/" gets it working.

Comment: Need to know what the redirect code looks like

Comment: @developerwjk Firebug shows it is 302

Comment: I actually meant the code showing how you are redirecting.

Comment: @developerwjk There isn't any explicit code to perform the redirect. I posted my web.xml

Comment: @developerwjk is specific redirect code required? I thought that posting to j_security_check would automatically redirect the user to the originally request page.